# TikZ tree (not aligned text at a given level of the tree because use exponent)

Tags: tikz-trees

I have a tree (see example) for which the text at level 1 is not aligned since
one of the text uses some math expression with an exponent (i.e., `$\mathtt{int}^2$`).
Any idea how to get all the texts that are located at the same level of the tree aligned ?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
{\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[level distance=6mm]
  \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=8mm]
  \node (1){$\mathtt{atom}$}
    child {node (2){$\mathtt{atom}$}}
    child {node (3){$\mathtt{int}^2$}}
    child {node (4){$\mathtt{collection}$}
     child {node (5){$\mathtt{int}$}}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `every node/.append style={anchor=base}` so that all nodes are aligned at their base point

## Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
{\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[level distance=6mm,every node/.append style={anchor=base}]
  \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=8mm]
  \node (1){$\mathtt{atom}$}
    child {node (2){$\mathtt{atom}$}}
    child {node (3){$\mathtt{int}^2$}}
    child {node (4){$\mathtt{collection}$}
     child {node (5){$\mathtt{int}$}}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the `anchor=base` key for the tree.

## Example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
{\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[level distance=6mm, anchor=base]
  \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=8mm]
  \node (1){$\mathtt{atom}$}
    child {node (2){$\mathtt{atom}$}}
    child {node (3){$\mathtt{int}^2$}}
    child {node (4){$\mathtt{collection}$}
     child {node (5){$\mathtt{int}$}}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]